# Reverse Proxy for API

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, proxy, wordpress-rest-api

I have a WordPress installation, but it's behind an IP whitelist firewall. I'd like to make the raw JSON data therein publicly accessible only via the WordPress API. The entire WP instance can't be made public, but I can whitelist an IP for a client/host proxy server.

Diagram attached.

I'd imagine some sort of Node or React setup, but am hoping for something more direct, like a reverse proxy setup using Apache/NGINX. This service won't have any sort of front-end at all. It's only for grabbing and returning JSON from WordPress.

Listen for requests, pass requests to WP, return JSON to requester.

I'm sure something like this has been solved for, I'm just having a hard time getting started.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, couldn't you :

1. Have a simple page on your server calling your wordpress api and printing the JSON result ;
2. Have a vhost well configured to use different IP for Wordpress and JSON service (see [Apache Doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html));
3. Whitelist the IP of the JSON service ?

Comment: Hey @lucas Yes, I believe what you outline would work. Actually I think it's just a rephrasing of my question. It's the #2 piece that I'm most in-the-dark about. How to connect the service that's behind the firewall to a public service that isn't.  

1: Yes, I have a simple page capable of returning/printing JSON  

2: This is where I'm stuck. I've been reading about using reverse proxy and think that might be my path forward, if I can get it configured.  

3: Yes, that's what I was hoping for.